# Angular regex validation

Tags: angular, regex, angular-validation, angular-validator

User is going to input in the form and only allowed numbers separated by comma.

I want to allow space after comma but not before comma and white space anywhere else is fine. (I only want to add numbers not alphabets).

I want to use this in Angular Validator pattern like Validator, pattern (`"[0-9,\s]+\s*$"`)

Correct: `1123, 1232312, 12323213, 13123213213`

Wrong: `123 ,1232123 ,1221323123 , 12312313`

I used this `"[0-9,\s]+\s*$"` but it's not allowing any space.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex should be:

```
^(?:[0-9]+,\s)+(?:[0-9]+)$
```

With

- `^` - Starts with.
- `(?:[0-9]+,\s)` - A non-capturing group that contains at least one numeric character, followed by a comma (`,`) and whitespace (`\s`).
- `+` - At least one occurence for previous group.

  - Note: Could be replaced with `*` if want to match a group of numeric characters only for example: "1234".
- `(?:[0-9]+)` - A non-capturing group that contains at least one numeric character.
- `$` - Ends with.

[Demo @ regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xlZGIp/1)